# Gap between two bar graphs using Highchart

Tags: highcharts

Is there anyone know if this kind of graph is available in Highcharts? See image below

[image]

I can't find a way to have a gap "idle time" between the two bar graph in period of time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about using just one more series, which isn't displayed in legend, but have white background and enabled dataLabels? Isn't that working?

Simple example using `columnrange` series: http://jsfiddle.net/R5qLB/1/

Comment: See updated answer - if you want to put there 'idle' text, add one more series with 'idles'.